# How do you define functional testing with two popular and seemingly contradictory explanations?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, functional-testing, system-testing

I've been researching the definition of functional testing and can't come across a concrete explanation and would appreciate some additional info to help reconcile this.

The two main ideas I have come across are:

1. Functional Testing as a Testing Type and is comprised of the following Testing Levels: Unit Testing, Integration Testing, System Testing and Acceptance Testing.

[image]

2. Functional Testing as a separate level from Unit Testing and Integration Testing (sometimes a subset of System Testing other times precedes it) that tests the product end-to-end with a Black-box approach. Purpose is to verify all functional specifications defined.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing terminology is garbage. Everyone has their own terminology. Therefore even if you settle on one of the definitions, you should expect that others may not understand you.

[Personally](http://qala.io/blog/holes-in-test-terminology.html), I think we need to stick with the *etymology* that the term alludes to. *Functional* test means (to me) the fact that it checks business logic (functionality). We can write these tests on any level - Unit, System level, etc. It's a job of developers to determine where such test would be most effective.

But again - you'll hear people referring to Selenium tests when they say "Functional" %)

Also, I don't think that your 1st definition means that Functional Testing *comprises* of the levels. I think it means that it can be *conducted* on different levels. Which is similar to what I just wrote.

PS: Acceptance Testing is not a level either - it's the fact that you accept new code. As opposed to Regression Testing which checks that what previously worked keeps working. Though there is also a User Acceptance testing - which refers to end users playing with the system.

Comment: This has definitely helped clear things up. The lack of a source of truth around these terms as you wrote definitely added to my frustration trying to organize all this information into something concrete. I agree that functional tests should be conducted in whatever level appropriate. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its about different types of testing classification.
In case 1 we got separation of functional and non-functional tests.
This classification about **as what kind of cases are tested**:
 - in functional scenarios we check *what system able to do* and does it meets requirements. 
For example: is user able to authorize via facebook.
 - in non-functional scenarios we check *how system does is*: is it secure enough? Is it clear and simple (UX, usability and so on)? What about optimization and performance?

In case 2 we got separation based on isolation level.
This classification about **what part of our product is tested**:
Are we testing separate code module, integration of two services or whole product?
In this classification *functional tests* are about level of abstraction, when we make tests of single business-scenario (user function).